# How do I access branched versions of my app in browser?

Tags: git, branch

I'm very new to git and Ruby on Rails and am working on my first app. I'm currently using a git branching model described here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

I've got my two primary branches: `master` and `develop`. Whenever I create feature branches off of `develop` or even merge into `develop`, I can't seem to see the results when I visit `http://localhost:3000`. The page is displaying what I presume is the `master` branch. How can I view `develop` or even a `feature-*` branch without merging into `master`?

Comment: It should show whatever branch you're currently switched to although,depending on what changes you've made, you may have to kill and restart the sever.

Comment: What exactly do you have in the hosted directory of local webserver? Is it just the main directory of the git repository?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing...I needed to clear my cache. Your answer is right, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers found in the comments of the original question.

I needed to clear my cache. Some changes require restarting the rails server as mentioned by @kevtufc